# SessionState MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I wanted my `sessionstate` to run `InProc`, and have a 20 minute `timeout`.

If I do not add this to the web config, what will the default session information be. I had it working with storing/retrieving things to the session, so I'm assuming it was set to InProc since I don't have a stateserver or anything. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default session state is stored InProc and timeout duration is 20 minutes, so nothing needs to be set in web.config. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,your default session mode is In process mode with timeout period of 20 minutes. but you can also mange this by specify setting in web.config as follows :

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <sessionstate 
   mode="inproc"
   cookieless="false" 
   timeout="20" //specify your timeout 
   sqlconnectionstring="sql server connectionstring"
   server="127.0.0.1" //in 'inproc' mode localwebserver.
   port="42424" 
   />
  </system.web>
 </configuration>
```